# Как переделать SQL-запрос в запрос LINQ C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Допустим, есть 2 списка List - p и q.
p = {bread, eggs} и q = {bread, milk}.

Нужно получить новый список {bread, eggs, milk}.
k - это количество элементов в списке.
Есть SQL-запрос:

```
    insert into Ck
    select p.item1, p.item2, ... , p.itemk-1, q.itemk-1
    from Lk-1 p, Lk-1 q
    where p.item1 = q.item1, p.item2 = q.item2, ... , p.itemk-2 = q.itemk-2,
    p.itemk-1 < q.itemk-1
```

Его нужно как-нибудь переделать в LINQ-запрос. Это пока все, что удалось придумать.

```
            var nextCadidate = (from pitem in pData
                                join qitem in qData on pitem equals qitem
                                select new { newitem = pitem.Concat(qitem) }
                                );
```

Можно, конечно, и не переделывать, а как-нибудь циклом это сделать - нужны любые идеи.

Comment: Вам не нужен join здесь. Надо union и distinct. Хоть в sql, хоть в linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> q = new List<string> { "bread", "eggs" };
List<string> p = new List<string> { "bread", "milk" };
List<string> r = q.Concat(p).Distinct().ToList();
```